# Making a conversion program, it errors at my else if statements ')' expected and my jlabel setText isnt working either.. bunch of errors

Tags: if-statement, jlabel, settext

Ok so I took out the beginning which was just labeling them.. it keeps erroring near my if else statements and also my settext statments? says ")" expected and illegal start of expression for if else. I'm new to this and confused any help would be appreciated. also, for this I'm supposed to be using parameters, the lesson i got barely explains what that is.. so any help.. thank you

```
    inches = Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText()); // get txt from txtfield to show te value
     feet = Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());
     yards = Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());
      metres = Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());
    //choose conversions 1-4
    //conv1
     String textfieldinput = jTextField1.getText(); //getting txt and making it check if equal

    if(textfieldinput.equals("1"))
    centimetres = inches*2.54;
    jLabel8.setText( inches + "inches" + " = " + inches*2.54 "cm");

    //conv2
     if else (textfieldinput.equals("2")) 
    centimetres = feet*30;
    jLabel8.setText(feet + "feet" + " = " + feet*30 "cm");

    //conv3
     if else (textfieldinput.equals("3"))
           metres = yards*0.91;
      jLabel8.setText(yards + "yards" + " = " + yards*0.91 "metres");
    //conv4
     if else (textfieldinput.equals("4"))
          kilometres = metres*1.6;
 jLabel8.setText(metres "metres" + " = " + metres*1.6 "km");
```

Comment: first time posting sorry made it alittle messy..oops

Comment: `if else` is invalid syntax. Maybe you just meant `else`? Also, you seem to be missing lots of `{...}` blocks...

Comment: it says not a statement ... 'else' without 'if' ... if i just put else. im going to add { now bc i did not put those.